# Is there a way to send data from logstash to opensearch using data_stream?

Tags: logstash, opensearch

When I try to use data_stream in logstash output pipeline, it gives below error.

[ERROR][logstash.outputs.opensearch] Unknown setting 'data_stream' for opensearch

Comment: I don't think it is supported, at least there it seems to not have this option in the [code](https://github.com/opensearch-project/logstash-output-opensearch/blob/main/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch.rb), There is also an [open issue](https://github.com/opensearch-project/logstash-output-opensearch/issues/94) about it in the opensearch repository.

Comment: @leandrojmp Thanks for the input. However I figured out the solution. We could create an index template including property `"data_stream": { },`. Now in the output block index should match with the index pattern we defined in the index template. And finally we are good to create data_stream automatically when we execute the pipeline, and data are getting pushed there in the data stream.